# Using "find" to access a value in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, indexof

So I have been brushing up a bit on c++ and found out I am very rusty in comparison to my other languages. I have been working on this problem from codewars.com

> Given a list lst and a number N, create a new list that contains each number of lst at most N times without reordering. For example if N = 2, and the input is [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3], you take [1,2,3,1,2], drop the next [1,2] since this would lead to 1 and 2 being in the result 3 times, and then take 3, which leads to [1,2,3,1,2,3].

To accomplish this task I wanted to create a multidimentional vector to hold unique values of the provided list in the first dimension and corresponding number of occurences in the second dimension. However, I was unfamiliar with c++'s syntax to accomplish this, so I just made 2 separate vectors.(instances, countOfInstance)

Essentially what my algorithm will do is:

- loop through the provided array(arr)
- check to see if the value in "arr" does not exists in "instances"
- If not found then push the value in "arr" to "instances",
- add a counting value of 1 that corresponds to this index in "countOfInstance"
- and then add the value in "arr" to the nFilteredVector.

If the value in "arr" is found in "instances" then:

- Find the index value of "arr" in "instances"
- Use this index to find its corresponding count value in "countOfInstances"
- Determine if the count is less than the provided "N"
- if less than "N" add to "nFilteredVector"
- Then increment the value in "countOfInstances"

However, when I try to access the index of "CountOfInstances" with index of "instances" i get an odd error

> no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'std::vector'
>         if (countOfInstances[std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(),arr[i])] <=2){

Correct me if I am wrong, but it is my understanding that the find function returns the index value of the found element. I was wanting to use that index value to access "countOfInstances" vector.

Can someone please help me figure out the correct syntax of what I am looking for. Bonus points for integrating "instances" and "countOfInstance" as a multidimentional vector!!

```
#include <algorithm> 
            std::vector<int> deleteNth(std::vector<int> arr, int n)
            {
              std::vector<int> nFilteredVector;
              std::vector<int> instances;
              std::vector<int> countOfInstances;

              for (int i =0; i < arr.size();i++){
                if(std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(),arr[i])==instances.end()){//value not found need to add corresponding value to instances vector then add an element of 1 to the correpeonding index of the countOfInstance vector.
                  instances.push_back(arr[i]);
                  countOfInstances.push_back(1);
                  nFilteredVector.push_back(arr[i]);
                }else{ // value is found just need to increment the value in countOfInstances
                  //find the instance of the value in arr in the instance vector, use that value to find the corresponding value in countOfInstance
                  if (countOfInstances[std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(),arr[i])] <=n){
                    nFilteredVector.push_back(arr[i]);      
                  }
                  countOfInstances[std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(),arr[i])]++;
              }



              return nFilteredVector;
            }
```

Here are some examples of what codewars will be testing for

```
                {
                Assert::That(deleteNth({20,37,20,21}, 1), Equals(std::vector<int>({20, 37, 21})));
                Assert::That(deleteNth({1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2}, 3), Equals(std::vector<int>({1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2})));
              }
```

Comment: Usage of a `std::map` or `std::unorderd_map` instead of `std::vector` would simplify this assignment greatly.

Comment: That's honestly a good idea, but I would still like to know how to find the index value of an element in one array and use its returning index value to access another element in another array

Comment: So all you want to know is how to get the index of what `std::find` returns?  If so, then I think you could have simplified the question somewhat, as it doesn't matter what your program's purpose is .

Comment: More or less. I'm mainly trying to pin down the error and document my reasoning and purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is get the index of the found item in a `std::vector`, the following does this job using [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

auto iter = std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(),arr[i]);
if ( iter != instances.end())
{
   // get the index of the found item
   auto index = std::distance(instances.begin(), iter);
   //...
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks I'll try that out! I just have one questions about the whole != end logic. If we have a list of items and the item we are searching for is the last item in the list, what happens and how can i circumvent this edge case?

Comment: I'm just kinda suprised c++ doesnt have a function like "indexOf()" in Java

Comment: The `end()` iterator points to one past the last item.  So there really is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `std::find` return an iterator on `instances`. You cannot use an iterator from one list on another and  you cannot use an iterator as an index.

What you could do is use 
`std::find(instances.begin(), instances.end(), arr[i]) - instances.begin()` 
as your index. This is a bit ugly, so  you might also want to look a bit more at iterators and how to use them.

Comment: Hmm I assumed an iterator was more or less just an integer used to locate the element in question? I'll have to look more into that then.